# Import Weather into Google Sheets

Tags: html, json, import, google-sheets-formula, weather

I am trying to import the extended 14-day forecast into Google Sheets.  Some of the research I have been looking for are outdated and I would love some help for my knowledge gaps.

I tried =importXML and =importHTML and get an Error that says Cannot Fetch URL.
In cell A2 is the URL:  `"https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/mexico/mexico-city/ext"` 
In cell B2 is this formula with xpath: `=IMPORTXML(A2,"//*[@class='zebra tb-wt fw va-m tb-hover']")` 
I also tried in B2: `=IMPORTHTML(A2, "table", 2)`

I also read weather sites may use scripting so I'd have to try importJSON.
I added to Google Sheets App Script from: https://gist.github.com/allenyllee/c764c86ed722417948fc256b7a5077c4#file-import_json_appsscript-js 
I then tried:
`=IMPORTJSON("https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/usa/atlanta/ext?$format=json",table,2)`

All gave me errors like Error Fetching URL.

Any instructions/clarifications would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Can also try with Google Weather or Weather.com or Accuweather if easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extract the `<script type="text/javascript">` from web source and parse `var data`

```
function getWeatherForecast() {
  var url = 'https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/mexico/mexico-city/ext'
  var fetchedUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  if (fetchedUrl) {
    var html = fetchedUrl.getContentText().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm, "")
    var data = html.match(/var data=([^<]+)<\/script>/g)
    var jsn = JSON.parse(data[0].slice(9,-10))
    const header = Object.keys(jsn.detail[0]);
    var result = [header, ...jsn.detail.map(o => header.map(h => Array.isArray(o[h]) ? o[h].join(",") : o[h]))];
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    sh.getRange(1,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result)
  }
}
```

[image]

However, it seems that after a few tests, the site has blocked the google ip address on my side

> IP: 107.178.203.254You have been blocked because we have registered an unusual amount of traffic from your IP address.Please contact webmaster@timeanddate.com if you need more information or believe that this is a mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Seems like Accuweather blocked IP, too.  If anyone has workarounds please advise :)